# Group values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multi array from a dynamic list and extract the values like this:

```
$count = sizeof($ajax_array[app_id]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $app_id[$i] = $ajax_array['app_id'][$i];
  $company[$i] = $ajax_array['company'][$app_id[$i]];
  $sheriff[$i] = $ajax_array['sheriff'][$app_id[$i]];
  $app_number[$i] = $ajax_array['app_number'][$app_id[$i]];
}
```

What I need to do now is use this values to create groups (perhaps into another multi array) first group will be all with the same $company[$i] value and then with the same $sheriff[$i] value.

In the end of the day I need a list displaying:
`company "y" have this app_number "x","y","z" going to sheriff "x".`

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood what you need, is it something like this?

```
<?php

$ajax_array['app_id'][0] = 0;
$ajax_array['app_id'][1] = 1;
$ajax_array['app_id'][2] = 2;
$ajax_array['app_id'][3] = 3;

$ajax_array['company'][0] = 'first c';
$ajax_array['company'][1] = 'first c';
$ajax_array['company'][2] = 'third c';
$ajax_array['company'][3] = 'forth c';

$ajax_array['sheriff'][0] = 'first s';
$ajax_array['sheriff'][1] = 'second s';
$ajax_array['sheriff'][2] = 'first s';
$ajax_array['sheriff'][3] = 'forth s';

$ajax_array['app_number'][0] = 'app_0';
$ajax_array['app_number'][1] = 'app_1';
$ajax_array['app_number'][2] = 'app_2';
$ajax_array['app_number'][3] = 'app_3';


$count = sizeof($ajax_array['app_id']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $app_id[$i] = $ajax_array['app_id'][$i];
    $company[$i] = $ajax_array['company'][$app_id[$i]];
    $sheriff[$i] = $ajax_array['sheriff'][$app_id[$i]];
    $app_number[$i] = $ajax_array['app_number'][$app_id[$i]];

    $rearranged_company[$company[$i]][$sheriff[$i]] = $app_number[$i];

}

print_r($rearranged_company);
```